# How to configure the starting page of page numbering in Asciidoctor

Tags: pdf, yaml, asciidoctor, page-numbering, asciidoctor-pdf

I am using asciidoctor and asciidoctor-pdf. I want to start the page numbering after the third page. How can i do that in asciidoctor in the .yml file ?

My current configuration for the footer is

```
footer:
  font_size: $base_font_size_small
  # NOTE if background_color is set, background and border will span width of page
  border_color: DDDDDD
  border_width: 0.25
  height: $base_line_height_length * 2.5
  line_height: 1
  padding: [$base_line_height_length / 2, 1, 0, 1]
  vertical_align: top
  recto:
    #columns: "<50% =0% >50%"
    right:
      content: '{page-number}'
  verso:
    #columns: $footer_recto_columns
    left:
      content: $footer_recto_right_content
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with **Asciidoctor PDF 2.0**, you can update your asciidoctor-pdf with:

```
gem install asciidoctor-pdf
```

Page numbering is not as straight forward as one might think because you not only have page number, you also have *virtual page numbers*. You can look at the new [asciidoctor-pdf documentation](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/), check [Page Numbers](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/page-numbers/) and [Configure the Page Numbers](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/theme/page-numbers/). I assume page 3 is after your table of content, see all the parameters you have, but you will simply need to add something like this in your theme:

```
page:
  numbering:
    start-at: after-toc
```